# onChange no actualiza el estado en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un convertidor de unidades con react y tengo el siguiente problema:

Cuando ingreso el valor a convertir el resultado siempre va un paso atras, es decir, si ingreso 100 es como si ingresara 10.

Dejo el codigo aca:

```
const [kilometros, setKilometros] = useState(0)
const [millas, setMillas] = useState(0)
const [nudos, setNudos] = useState(0)

function calcularKmh(event) {
    setKilometros(event.target.value)
    setMillas(kilometros * 1.609344)
    setNudos(kilometros * 1.852)
    console.log(millas,nudos)
}

function calcularMph(event){
    setMillas(event.target.value)
    setKilometros(millas * 1.609344)
    setNudos(millas * 1.150779)
}

function calcularKts(event){
    setNudos(event.target.value)
    setKilometros(nudos * 1.852)
    setMillas(nudos * 1.150779)
}

return (
    <div className='medidas'>
        <form>
            <div>
                <input placeholder='Velocidad en KM/H' type='text' value={kilometros} onChange={calcularKmh} /> <span>KM/H</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input placeholder='Velocidad en MP/H' type='text' value={millas} onChange={calcularMph} /> <span>MP/H</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input placeholder='Velocidad en KTS' type='text' value={nudos} onChange={calcularKts} /><span>KTS</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

Todos los cambios se hacen un paso despues, que deberia cambiar?

Comment: Seguramente eso debe estar pasando por hacer el `console.log()` inmediatamente después de setear el estado. Para entender porqué esa no es una buena práctica, te recomiendo que leas un artículo que escribí sobre eso y así puedas tener una explicación completa: [Dentro de la caja negra de “setState”](https://desarrollos-web-urquiza.medium.com/dentro-de-la-caja-negra-de-setstate-69001c7c6ea4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los hooks de React son asíncronos, en otras palabras, que hagas un setKilometros en una línea, y en la siguiente uses la variable kilometros, no te garantiza que el valor esté actualizado.

Para solucionarlo deberías hacer algo así:

```
function calcularKmh(event) {
      const valorKilometros = event.target.value;
      setKilometros(valorKilometros)
      setMillas(valorKilometros * 1.609344)
      setNudos(valorKilometros * 1.852)
  }
```

Si te fijas, creo una const nueva con el nuevo valor de los kilómetros, y utilizo esa variable para setear el estado y hacer todos los otros cálculos.

Deberías hacer algo similar en el resto de las funciones.

Comment: Lo pude resolver asi con este metodo! gracias!